# How to create a curved rectangle?

Tags: java, android, view, android-custom-view

I want to create a custom view like this:

[image]

But I am no able to do that. I really do not know what should I do to create that View. Can anyone help me please? I really need your help.

**CustomView.class**

```
  public class CustomView extends View {

  private int width;
  private int height;

  public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public CustomView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    width = width;
    height = height;
  }
}
```

Comment: Whats the output of your customView.class?

Answer (score 0):

create drawable resource with below xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="0dp"
        android:left="-60dp"
        android:right="-60dp"
        android:top="-140dp">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

in your layout file set background with this drawable on top layout.